# Find top documents which matched the query of words

Tags: algorithm, document, software-design, cpu-word

So basically in this problem, we have 1000000 Documents:

Documents have:
-Text (contains a lot of words)
-Date
-DocId
.. and so on

and we have a query which has some words (max 1000):

So we now the problem is we have first find the intersection between Documents and Query and then top K top documents which have the most number of words matched.

For Example:

D1 - w1, w2, w3, w4, ... wn
D2 - w2, w4, w5, x2
D3 - a1, a2, w1, x1, x2

Q(w1,a1,w4,w5,x1,w5,w6)

so now doing the intersection of queries and docs

D1 - w1,w4,w5,w6  - 4 match
D2 - w4,w5        - 2 match
D3 - a1,x1,w1     - 3 match

So top 2 Docs are D1 and D3

I have tried to put words to document mapping in a 2d matrix.

```
       D1 D2 D3  
w1     1     1  
w2     1  1  
w3     1         
.  
.  
.  
a1           1    
a2           1  
x1           1  
x2        1  1
```

From this matrix, I tried to find numbers but the interviewer was not happy.

Please help guys !!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to program it yourself, you'd probably build a hash table with the 1000 words, then go through the documents and check all words for matches. Keep a list of the k best matches around and update it after each document.

In real life, I would stuff the documents into a PostgreSQL database, create a full text search index on the text and run an SQL query containing the search words. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Thanks for replying @laurenz.
This is an interview question. So in your approch, you will first iterate on each document and in each document, you will iterator on each word and will keep matching it your hash table and will maintain the top k best matches documents.

What will be the complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: No. I would first go through all 1000 words and build a hash table. The complexity should be O(documents * words per document + search words). Do you know what a hash table is?

Comment: yeah, I know what hash table is.

And in my approach complexity was O (documents * number_of_words_in_query) and the interviewer was still not convinced with it.

Any other way you suggest to do this problem.

Comment: I wouldn't be convinced by your answer, but mostly because I'd wonder how you want to store and manage that matrix. And your algorithm's complexity is O(documents * words per document * search words), because it seems you are using a nested loop for this.